# How to Correctly Store Each Bootstrap Accordion Group Within a Separate PartialView

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Attempting to get this right has been very frustrating experience. The scenario is that when a user clicks the second header, I call the server using Ajax and then load the result list into the second PartialView. I surrounded the second partial with a div with an id in order to override the content with the data coming from the server, but unfortunately, this does not work right. The main goal is to make sure that the second list is always updated from the db.

Below is the current structure:

**View:**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewOne", Model.One)
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel2">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialViewTwo", Model.Two)
</div>
```

**PartialView1:**

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        First Group Items
    </a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="MyLightboxes" class="list-group">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
          {
               <button type="button" class="list-group-item"    value="@item.PersonID">@item.Name</button>
           }
    </div>
</div>
```

**PartialView2:**

```
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
<h4 class="panel-title">
    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        First Group Items
    </a>
</h4>
</div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="MyLightboxes" class="list-group">
            @foreach (var item in Model2)
          {
               <button type="button" class="list-group-item"    value="@item.PersonID">@item.Name</button>
           }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code where you fetch content via ajax and update the div ? Do you have any js errors in console ? Is it making the ajax call ? (check your browser network call)

Comment: The Ajax code is located in the View. And yes, there was an 404 error and corrected it thanks to you. There are a few problems now however; surrounding the second partial with <div id="PartialViewTwo"> messes the accordion panel up. I attempted to remove the div and then added a panel2 id next to class="panel panel-default" (updated the question accordingly), now it seems to work by replacing that id with the incoming html data except that the panel flashes then collapses and needs to be clicked again to open